# MVC3 Security Tips

Tags: security, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using AspNetSqlMembershipProvider and created my pages for provisioning.  Now that I have this working I'm wondering on how best to utilize security throughout the site.  For the controllers I can use [Authorize], but where do I go next?  I mean do I just clutter the views with Roles.IsUserInRole, and where else do I need to put in checks.  Any good example sites on how to deal with this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you should not clutter your views with `Roles.IsUserInRole`, that's not a view's responsibility to check roles, that's a controller/authorize filter job to populate your view model so that in view you only have:

```
@if (Model.ShouldDisplaySomeSection)
{
    ... // some section
} else {
   ... // not authorized
}
```

Also note that if you decorate a controller action with the standard `[Authorize]` attribute and a user has no sufficient roles this action might never be executed and the view never hit.

Personally I find the [Developer Highway Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/security/aa473878.aspx) as an extremely useful security checklist even if it is not restricted to MVC.

Answer (score 3):

I created a solution where I derived from the `Authorize` attribute and in my own attribute I introduced a `param[]` array of an `enum` type called `UserRoles`, so that I skip the magic strings.

Then for the cluttering of the views. Well, I guess you should ask yourself when you are about to write `IsUserInRole` in the view if you really should write that there. I think you should try to keep the views as clean as possible and try to sort as much out in the `ViewModel` as possible. And if you can't do that, consider a HTML Helper.